# My javascript for loop is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the folowing code:

```
var transitionsSettingsClass = document.getElementsByClassName("transitionsSettings");  
var transitionsSettingsClassLenght = transitionsSettingsClass.length;  
for (i=0; i < transitionsSettingsClassLenght; i++);   
{   
    transitionsSettingsClass[i].setAttribute("data-transition",transitionsSettings);    
};
```

I know that transitionsSettingsClassLenght = 6 because I have checked it with alert. But when I put an alert inside cycle then it shows only 1-time (it should show 6-times). An also attribute data-transition is not set. But when I replace "i" inside transitionsSettingsClass[i] with transitionsSettingsClass[0] my first element changes and it is working. This script is supposed to change attribute data-transition in 6 elements.

Comment: It's "Length" not "Lenght" (though JavaScript doesn't care :-)

Comment: Is there a reason to spell 'length' 'lenght'? That would be really confusing to me.

Comment: @itdoesntwork perhaps English is not one of this person's strongest languages ...

Comment: @pointy I was just pointing out that he spelled it right once but consistently spelled it wrong later. I thought it may have been on purpose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end of

```
for (i=0; i < transitionsSettingsClassLenght; i++);
```

The `for` here only commands the code before the `;`, that is nothing.

I'd recommend you to use the most frequent javascript style, [as explicited by Google](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Code_formatting), as it helps avoid this kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with jquery each method?

```
 $('.transitionsSettings').each(function(index) {
        $(this).setAttribute("data-transition",transitionsSettings);
    });
```

Comment: yeah... i see that now, but anyway i would always rather use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a sidenote:

---

In all modern browsers you can set `data-` attributes by calling

```
node.dataset.transition = transitionsSettings;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is interpreted as follows:
`for (i=0; i < transitionsSettingsClassLenght; i++);

{

    transitionsSettingsClass[i].setAttribute("data-transition",transitionsSettings);

};`

The first line: 
`for (i=0; i < transitionsSettingsClassLenght; i++);`
 is executed 6 times as Javascript thinks its a single statement. Then it encounters 
`{

    transitionsSettingsClass[i].setAttribute("data-transition",transitionsSettings);

};` 
which is executed once as a block. Removing the `;` from the end of the for loop will solve the problem.

Comment: Using the 1 True Brace Style (1TBS -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS) will also help avoid such problems.